# Kubernetes nginx ingress cannot find backend service

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have deployed my API to Kubernetes on AKS through kubectl command from my local machine. But the nginx ingress is not able to resolve the backend endpoint. The ingress logs has an error  `The service 'hello-world/filter-api' does not have any active endpoint`

**Steps followed:**

**Install dapr on AKS**

- dapr init -k --set global.tag=1.1.2

**Install nginx ingress on AKS**

- helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
- helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -f ...\dapr\components\dapr-annotations.yaml --set image.tag=1.11.1 -n ingress-nginx

**Apply manifest**

- kubectl apply -f .\services\filter.yaml

**What did I try?**

- Verified the selectors and labels
- Followed the steps mentioned [Troublshooting nginx ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/troubleshooting/)

I tried to deploy this to local Kubernetes cluster on windows with docker desktop. This works fine. What am I missing?

***filter.yaml***

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: filter-cm
  namespace: hello-world
  labels:
    app: hello-world
    service: filter
data:
  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
  ASPNETCORE_URLS: http://0.0.0.0:80
  PATH_BASE: /filter
  PORT: "80"

---

kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: filter
  namespace: hello-world
  labels:
    app: hello-world
    service: filter
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: filter
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
        service: filter
      annotations:
        dapr.io/enabled: "true"
        dapr.io/app-id: "filter-api"
        dapr.io/app-port: "80"
        dapr.io/config: "dapr-config"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: filter-api
          image: client/hello-world-filter-api:0.0.1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: filter-cm
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: filter-api
  namespace: hello-world
  labels:
    app: hello-world
    service: filter
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30001
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    service: filter

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: filter-ingress
  namespace: hello-world
  labels:
    app: hello-world
    service: filter
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /filter
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: filter-api
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: Did you use the cloud type deployment?
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.43.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml

Comment: I used helm to install nginx. helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -f .\..\dapr\components\dapr-annotations.yaml --set image.tag=1.11.1 -n ingress-nginx

Comment: The "filter-api" pod is up & running with no issue?

Comment: Yes pod is running without issues. But Pod logs has a log   The service 'hello-world/filter-api' does not have any active endpoint. When I hit the endpoint http://externalip/filter I’m trying nginx not found page

Comment: Can you post a `kubectl get svc filter-api -oyaml` and similar commands for the other resources? The `-oyaml` will output everything in a nicely readable format with various info.

Answer (score 0):

In the service selector, use matchLabels for the service to find the backend pods

example:

```
selector:
   matchLabels:
     service: filter
```